# Producing .xcarchive for target when building for iOS with CMake

Tags: ios, cmake, continuous-integration

I'm trying to automate iOS building through CMake, up to and including authoring .ipas. I have my provisioning profile and certificates set up, build is successful, but when I execute cmake --build I can't get .xcarchives to generate, and my POST_BUILD command (using xcodebuild) to author the .ipa is dependent on that.

I've tried setting some archive options though CMake (setting cmake_archive_output_directory), but there's a flag or option to set that can produce xcarchives during build, I don't know it. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Despite many attempts, a post-build command to xcodebuild archive never worked -- I'm still not sure why, either. What I ended up doing to work around this was have CMake generate a script.

So my create executable custom function does this:

It creates a script file if it doesn't already exist, then for each executable target, appends an xcodebuild command if it's not a duplicate:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${pathToTargetWorkspace} -scheme ${targetScheme} -configuration ${config} -archivePath ${pathToGeneratedArchive}.xcarchive archive
```

Then after building is finished, you just run the script with the aggregation of archive commands and it archives all the targets.